# Can we use file descriptors from the kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, file-descriptor

My question is regarding usage of file descriptors in linux. My general understanding from answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255144/where-is-file-descriptor-stored-in-process-memory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms) us the for each process/thread the opened files are maintained correspondingly.

However, if a file descriptor is returned from within the kernel code like what I have tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100453/reading-performance-registers-from-the-kernel) what happens to the regular scheme of things? To which process would this descriptor belong? Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: The kernel code deals with `struct file` objects internally. This is a reference-counted representation of a user-space *open file description* and is usually referenced by one or more process's file descriptors (although it can also be created purely for use within kernel code, for example via the `filp_open` function).

Comment: @IanAbbott I am using the function perf_event_open() which returns a file descriptor for event monitoring. Where would this descriptor be stored?